# Selenium Chromedriver working with Mac local but not on Linux server

Tags: selenium, maven, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

I have a Java application that is running perfectly on local environment but on when it's deployed to a Linux server.
The Chromedriver version is always correct because is automatically selected through **webdrivermanager** Maven dependency. I also downloaded the exact chromedriver version but is not working anyways so it's not a problem of driver versions.

I am running it on my Mac with Chrome and basically it opens two parallel executions of Java Selenium Chrome Driver and performs some operations. when I upload it to the server, it is running only if I use a single chrome driver session, otherwise it does not work. On the server I am using Chromium.

These are the various things I tried:

**Running with these options work on local environment but not on server**

```
        options.addArguments("--headless", "--no-sandbox", "start-maximized", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=1920,1200", "--ignore-certificate-errors", "--disable-extensions", "disable-infobars");
```

To make it work, I have to add `"--remote-debugging-port=59111"`. If I do this, it is not working anymore in local because it says `Exception is caughtorg.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created` but on the server is working with a single Thread running a single chrome driver instance.

For me it's fine if I have to specify some parameters for the Linux Server and some other for my Mac, but I am not finding a way to make it work on the server with two parallel instances.
I also tried to add `--disable-dev-shm-usage` which is suggested in some forums but is not working anyways.

EDIT:
If I run the program on the server without `"--remote-debugging-port=59111"` , then I get:

```
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager - Exporting webdriver.chrome.driver as /home/forge/.cache/selenium/chromedriver/linux64/98.0.4758.102/chromedriver
Starting ChromeDriver 98.0.4758.102 (273bf7ac8c909cde36982d27f66f3c70846a3718-refs/branch-heads/4758@{#1151}) on port 36404
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Exception is caughtorg.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist
Build info: version: '4.1.2', revision: '9a5a329c5a'
System info: host: 'site1', ip: '127.0.0.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.4.0-94-generic', java.version: '11.0.13'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--headless, start-maximized, --disable-gpu, --window-size=1920,1200, --ignore-certificate-errors, --disable-extensions, disable-infobars], extensions: []}}], desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--headless, start-maximized, --disable-gpu, --window-size=1920,1200, --ignore-certificate-errors, --disable-extensions, disable-infobars], extensions: []}}}]
```

Comment: Don't think you want two parallel browser sessions using the same debug port.  Don't set that... Selenium will set it for you.  (or if you must, set each session to a different port.)

Comment: I tried it. If I put no port, on the local machine is working, on the remote server NOT. It says that no debugger port has been found. If I put two different ports is not working anyways. Any other suggestion?

Comment: I added more info can you check?

Comment: this means that the browser failed to drop the file that chromedriver needs to set sessionID and port.  Maybe check permissions on the server.  When the browser is launched in devMode it'll create a directory and the file that chromedriver reads to get the sessionID.  You should confirm that Chrome launches manually, check major version against the driver...  you should also use a sleep between each driver/thread launch.  (maybe debug with a single thread first...)  It may also help to download the driver yourself instead of using webdrivermanager.

Comment: If you are using java, you can use this to disable the version checking: System.setProperty ("webdriver.chrome.disableBuildCheck", "true");